# Copy-paste loop with skipped values in VBA

Tags: loops, excel, for-loop, copy-paste, vba

I am fairly new to code-writing in general and VBA in particular.

I have tried to write a fairly simple macro that copies values from one cell to another on a daily basis, however I am wondering if there is a way to have fewer variables for the loop counters, in other words, can a loop counter skip certain values?

```
Private Sub YesButton_Click()
Dim z As Integer
Dim z1 As Integer
Dim z2 As Integer
Dim z3 As Integer
Dim z4 As Integer
Dim z5 As Integer
Dim z6 As Integer
Dim z7 As Integer
Dim z8 As Integer
Dim z9 As Integer
Dim z10 As Integer
Dim z11 As Integer
Dim z12 As Integer
Dim z13 As Integer

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'turn off autocalc to speed up copy paste process

For z = 5 To 16
Sheet68.Range("H" & z) = Sheet68.Range("D" & z).Value
Next z

For z1 = 21 To 33
Sheet68.Range("H" & z1) = Sheet68.Range("D" & z1).Value
Next z1

For z2 = 38 To 51
Sheet68.Range("H" & z2) = Sheet68.Range("D" & z2).Value
Next z2

For z3 = 73 To 86
Sheet68.Range("H" & z3) = Sheet68.Range("D" & z3).Value
Next z3

For z4 = 92 To 94
Sheet68.Range("G" & z4) = Sheet68.Range("D" & z4).Value
Next z4

For z5 = 100 To 110
Sheet68.Range("G" & z5) = Sheet68.Range("D" & z5).Value
Next z5

For z6 = 115 To 126
Sheet68.Range("G" & z6) = Sheet68.Range("D" & z6).Value
Next z6

    For z7 = 131 To 142
Sheet68.Range("G" & z7) = Sheet68.Range("D" & z7).Value
Next z7

For z8 = 149 To 151
Sheet68.Range("G" & z8) = Sheet68.Range("D" & z8).Value
Next z8

For z11 = 157 To 164
Sheet68.Range("G" & z11) = Sheet68.Range("D" & z11).Value
Next z11

For z9 = 169 To 175
Sheet68.Range("G" & z9) = Sheet68.Range("D" & z9).Value
Next z9

For z10 = 180 To 186
Sheet68.Range("G" & z10) = Sheet68.Range("D" & z10).Value
Next z10

For z12 = 191 To 203
Sheet68.Range("H" & z12) = Sheet68.Range("D" & z12).Value
Next z12


Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic 'turn autocalc back on

Unload Me

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you could re-think your code. You will clearly need to readapt the sample to your own data.

### Declare a vector of ranges

The size of it, as many as your intervals are (I counted 14 in your case, but I might be wrong).

```
Dim ranges(1 To 5)
Dim j As Integer '<-- counter of the ranges
Dim k As Long '<-- counter of your loop
```

### Define your ranges

Here you define, as strings, your specific ranges. In my example I've put random numbers, but in your case should be "5-16", "21-23" etc.

```
ranges(1) = "1-2"
ranges(2) = "5-10"
ranges(3) = "15-20"
ranges(4) = "25-30"
ranges(5) = "35-40"
```

### Nest two loops

The outside one will loop through the ranges, the inside one will split the ranges and use the lower and upper bounds to loop through your cells

```
For j = 1 To 5
    For k = Split(ranges(j), "-")(0) To Split(ranges(j), "-")(1)
        'your code here
        'test it with a msgbox:
        MsgBox "k is now equal to " & k
    Next k
Next j
```

### To sum up

Your code should look something like this:

```
Dim ranges(1 To 14) '<-- not sure, please check it first!
Dim j As Integer, k As Long

ranges(1) = "5-16"
ranges(2) = "21-33"
'....
ranges(14) = "191-203"

For j = 1 To 14
    For k = Split(ranges(j),"-")(0) To Split(ranges(j),"-")(1)
        Sheet68.Range("G" & k) = Sheet68.Range("D" & k).Value
    Next k
Next j
```

Comment: one question: ranges that you define - it is just a function that you define in the code by providing values of the function based on the variable (in this case j)?

Comment: @mozgov_net, ranges is an array of string. When saying `Dim ranges(1 to 14)`, you're telling the compiler that the object `ranges` will be something like `("","","",...."")` with 14 empty places inside, numbered 1 to 14. Then, when you say something like `ranges(1)="1-3"`, it means the first element will be "1-3". So in the end you will have something like `ranges=("1-3", "5-7", ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just declare 1 int and use it for every loop. U give it a new value at the start of the loop anyway!

So:

```
Dim z As Integer

For z = 0 To 10 Step 1
     //Do something
Next

For z = 11 To 21 Step 1
     //Do something
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub YesButton_Click()
    Dim rngTemp As Range

    For Each rngTemp In Range("H5:H16, H21:H33, H38:H51, H73:H86, H191:H203")
        rngTemp.Value = rngTemp.Offset(, -4).Value
    Next rngTemp

    For Each rngTemp In Range("G92:G94, G100:G110, G115:G126, G131:G142, G149:G151, G157:G164, G169:G175, G180:G186")
        rngTemp.Value = rngTemp.Offset(, -3).Value
    Next rngTemp
End Sub
```